# Azure Python App Function no longer runs locally - module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async'

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have built an Azure App function in Python which was running fine locally within the virtual environment, and also worked fine when published to Azure.  I have come back to it now to do some further work, and when trying to run locally I get the below errors. There isn't much if anything available online that helps me understand why this error is occurring? I Have not changed the local code yet.

Python version

```
PS C:\temp\python_function> python --version
Python 3.7.1
```

Command to run

```
PS C:\temp\python_function> func host start
```

Result

```
[16/04/2019 1:11:51 AM] Starting language worker process:python  "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 60810 --workerId 0d7f3e36-a0a2-4478-aa49-c46e2c48cb77 --requestId 0e417fc7-eccb-4fcb-b889-b197ecfad53d --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[16/04/2019 1:11:51 AM] python process with Id=15040 started
[16/04/2019 1:11:51 AM] Adding dependency download request to python language worker
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] Traceback (most recent call last):
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]   File "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\worker.py", line 37, in main
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]     return aio_compat.run(azure.functions_worker.start_async(
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] AttributeError: module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async'
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] Traceback (most recent call last):
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]   File "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\worker.py", line 46, in <module>
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]     main()
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]   File "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\worker.py", line 37, in main
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM]     return aio_compat.run(azure.functions_worker.start_async(
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] AttributeError: module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async'
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] Language Worker Process exited.
[16/04/2019 1:11:52 AM] python exited with code 1
 AttributeError: module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async'.
```

Code added below:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import boto3
import uuid
import io
import os
import json
import requests
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import azure.functions as func
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
from scipy.interpolate import spline
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator

register_matplotlib_converters()

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    sns.set_style("dark")

    rowcount = req.params.get('rows')
    if not rowcount:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            rowcount = req_body.get('rows')

    if rowcount:
        rowcount = int(rowcount)

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        api_url = f'https://<removed>.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/tables/<removed>/all?&server=P781S001&ordercol=daily_sales_date&order=DESC&rowlimit={str(rowcount)}'
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Couldn't contact the InSite API. No data returned.",
                status_code=400
            )

        print os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
        dates = [i['daily_sales_date'] for i in json_data]
        values = [i['daily_sales'] for i in json_data]

        df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
        df['dates']  = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.plot(df['dates'].values, df['values'].values)
        ax.set(xlabel='date', ylabel='sales ($)',
            title='Sales from ' + str(min(df['dates'].values)) + ' to ' + str(max(df['dates'].values)))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
        ax.grid()

        session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id='',
            aws_secret_access_key='',
        )
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        img_data = io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(img_data, format='png')
        img_data.seek(0)

        s3.Bucket('api-dev-jupyter-notebook-s3').put_object(Key='graph_sales.png', ContentType='image/png', Body=img_data, ACL='public-read')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"You requested {rowcount} rows. Sample data {dates[0]} {str(values[0])}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This method requires you to state the amount of rows you want to query. E.g. rows=20.",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Comment: Can't help you if you don't provide your specific code with your python azure function.

Comment: Apologies, I had thought this to be more a packaging/publishing/environment issue rather than specific to the code (as the code hasn't changed since it last operated successfully) so thought the actual code to be non-relevant to the question. I have added it in.  Hopefully now, someone can help.

Comment: I think it is related to some changes from Azure related to "import azure.functions as func" where start_async is changed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

"UnInstall azure cli core tools and install using choclatey
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#v2
It works fine !. Hope that helps."

Reference : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24489#issuecomment-463158145

Comment: Thanks J.K - I'm a beginner at Python, so have never heard of or used choclatey but 'I'll review and see how I go!

Comment: The reference neither explains why this issue has occurred, nor any of the steps involved in either removing the cli core tools, or using choclatey to achieve the deployment? Nor does it explain how the issue only started occurring for seemingly no reason.  I'll attempt to gather information on using the above advice, but it's not actually that helpful.

Comment: Updating core-tools to Core Tools 2.4.419 helped me.

Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24489#issuecomment-473774309

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. While generally available internet documentation states you can use the below to launch your Python virtual environment on Windows:

```
Launch virtualenv
In your Command Prompt navigate to your project:

cd your_project
Within your project:

virtualenv env
Activate your virtualenv:

on Windows, virtualenv creates a batch file

\env\Scripts\activate.bat
to activate virtualenv on Windows, activate script is in the Scripts folder :

\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

This doesn't appear to work and causes (at least) the errors I've observed. Instead, I have followed the explicit instructions within the Microsoft article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python which does work.

```
PS C:\temp\python_function> py -3.6 -m venv .env
PS C:\temp\python_function> .env\scripts\activate
(.env) PS C:\temp\python_function> func host start
```