# how start a python function in local which is docker enabled

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-linux

I'm following the steps as described in the following link,
[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image)

when I'm trying to start my app with func host start, I'm getting the foll0wing error

```
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
[08-08-2019 12:58:50]   File "c:\users\sivasakthivelan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
[08-08-2019 12:58:50]     from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
[08-08-2019 12:58:50] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down Functions Host
```

Comment: agree @atline I just closed the article when I saw its from MS :P these issues common with window ;)

Comment: Similar error shows up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763964/unable-to-successfully-run-func-host-start-to-test-azure-function